# Git-svn out of memory

Tags: out-of-memory, git-svn

I'm trying to clone a reasonably big svn repository with git-svn and at a certain point I get a error message:

```
Failure loading plugin: APR: Can't create a character converter from 'UTF-8' to native encoding: Cannot allocate memory at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 5061
```

And sometimes a

```
Cannot allocate memory: zlib (compress2): out of memory: Compression of svndiff data failed at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 5061
```

error message. I still have ~3GB RAM free. What should I do so git-svn can utilize it?

(I'm doing this on RedHat Enterprise Linux 6.5 if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 0):

[From](https://superuser.com/questions/420511/git-cannot-allocate-memory-git-svn-rebase):

> This error message is about the memory git is trying to allocate --
>   it's more than what is free. This is most likely caused by a large
>   file having been checked into SVN. Unfortunately, there's no easy way
>   to fix it (apart from buying more memory) -- you would have to remove
>   the large file and the commit adding it from SVN.

However try following:

1. Increase swap memory
2. Increase ulimit

Comment: Yes, I was aware of this answer on Superuser. However, as I stated in the original question I have quite enough memory left, git just can't seem to be able to utilize it. For example my swap is still empty completely. I tried to increase ulimit though, it didn't help either.